# When we solve any differential equation should the solution be differentiable everywhere?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving $dy/dx = x/y$ to obtain $y=\pm \sqrt{(c-x^2)}$.

Then I try to prove that only one at a time can be a solution. My idea is:

Since y is differentiable and thus continuous if we have a $f(y_1)=\sqrt{(c-x^2)}$
and $f(y_2)=-\sqrt{(c-x^2)}$ then for some $y_0$ $f(x)=\sqrt{(c-x^2)}$ on $(y_0,y_0+ε)$ and $f(x)=-\sqrt{(c-x^2)}$ on $(y_0-ε,y_0)$.

So by continuity we need $\sqrt{(c-y_0^2)}=-\sqrt{(c-y_0^2)}$ => 
$\unicode{x21af}$ . So $y=\sqrt{(c-x^2)}$ or $y=-\sqrt{(c-x^2)}$

Would that argument work?

Comment: Yes I meant $dy/dx=x/y$, sorry.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. Both $x \mapsto \sqrt{c-x^2}$ and $x \mapsto -\sqrt{c-x^2}$ are solutions.

Comment: Im asking if for example we can have $f(1)=\sqrt{c-1}$ and $f(2)=-\sqrt{c-2}$

Comment: There are various ways of defining a solution, but in this particular case it presumably means a differentiable (hence continuous) function satisfying the equation and defined on a (connected) interval. In particular, the point $(x,0)$ can never lie on a trajectory for any $x$, so either $y>0$ for the entire solution or $y<0$ for the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you can say is that from the intermediate value theorem you would have to have a $y_3$ that is between $y_1$ and $y_2$ with $f(y_3)=0$ but that is prohibited by the original equation.

Comment: Yes, thats even better, but my question is can we require y to be continuous everywhere (so that we aplay IVT)?